# Partially applied isBefore function in Scala gives error

Tags: scala

I am trying to merge two sequences of dates in Scala such that the merged sequence has sorted elements. I am using a partial implementation of isBefore as follows:

```
  val seq1 = Seq(LocalDate.of(2014, 4, 5), LocalDate.of(2013, 6 ,7), LocalDate.of(2014, 3, 1))
  val seq2 = Seq(LocalDate.of(2012, 2, 2), LocalDate.of(2015, 2, 1))
  var arr = (seq1 ++ seq2).sortWith(_.isBefore(_) = 1)
  println(arr)
```

But it shows compilation error for the isBefore function:

```
 Multiple markers at this line
- missing arguments for method isBefore in class LocalDate; follow this method with `_' if you want to 
 treat it as a partially applied function
- missing arguments for method isBefore in class LocalDate; follow this method with `_' if you want to 
 treat it as a partially applied function
```

I am relatively new to Scala. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first there is no such term as partial implementation, at least i didn't heard of such, i guess you've meant partial application, but there is no partial application in this case, partial application is about curried functions, what complier is trying to tell you in your error message. Example of this:

```
def test(a: String)(f: String => String) = f(a)

val onString = test("hello world") _

onString(_.capitalize)

test: (a: String)(f: String => String)String
onString: (String => String) => String = <function1>
res8: String = Hello world
```

This is a partial application, you take a curried function, which returns another function and passes it one argument (partially applies it) and latter passes another argument.

As for you sorting problem, that should work. I don't which which library you are using but with Date time it's similar. I think the problem is in assignment `(_.isBefore(_) = 1)`, this is illegal. Should be like this:

```
val seq1 = Seq(LocalDate.parse("2014-04-05"), LocalDate.parse("2013-06-07"), LocalDate.parse("2014-03-01"))
val seq2 = Seq(LocalDate.parse("2012-02-02"), LocalDate.parse("2015-02-01"))
var arr = (seq1 ++ seq2).sortWith(_.isBefore(_))

arr: Seq[org.joda.time.LocalDate] = List(2012-02-02, 2013-06-07, 2014-03-01, 2014-04-05, 2015-02-01)
```